# Changing startup options in Nethack Cocoa

Tags: nethack

I find nethack cocoa works with MACos Mountain Lion. I would like to change default options before I start a character. I use to do this but have forgotten and the OS has changed too.

Comment: What version are you running? The standalone (downloaded from the web) or from the app store?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the Cocoa port handy, but if you can find the `nethack.nh` file you can set default configuration options.